# How use a variable outside a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem with the persistance of a variable in Node.js.

I make this routine:

```
var travelTimes;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    distance.get(
    {
        origin: hotel, 
        destination: data[i].ubicacion,
        language: 'es'
    },function(err, maps_data) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        travelTimes.push(data.ubication);
    });
}
console.log(travelTimes);
```

And the last line gives me `undefined`. I was searching and found it that because Node.js is asynchronous my variable `maps_data` only lives into the distance.get() callback, but I need that data to continue with my work. How can I make it live in all my code?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I use a variable outside of a callback?

You can't.
The variable is defined inside of that callback and that callback only.
This is why it is logging `undefined`.

You could fix it by putting the `console.log()` inside of your function.

```
var travelTimes;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    distance.get(
    {
        origin: hotel, 
        destination: data[i].ubicacion,
        language: 'es'
    },function(err, maps_data) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        travelTimes.push(data.ubication);
        console.log(travelTimes); // Now it's inside the callback
    });
}
```